# IconButton calling setState during onPressed shows no ripple effect

Tags: flutter

During the `onPressed` of my `IconButton` I need to update the database and then the UI so that the user sees feedback of the data change.  To do this I call `setState`, which successfully lets the `Widget` rebuild.  The problem is I'm no longer seeing the touch feedback ripple effect because the `Widget` rebuilds immediately.

```
var button = new IconButton(
    icon: new Icon(isMyBoolTrue ? Icons.undo : Icons.event_available),
    onPressed: () => setState(() => toggleDatabaseBool)
);
```

Answer (score 4):

The issue was I was creating an `ObjectKey` with an object that was re-created every time during `build`.  Solved the issue by using `ObjectKey` and the id field of my object instead of the object itself.

**Bad**

```
var card = new Card(
    key: new ObjectKey(goal), //the goal object was re-created during `build`
    child: button
);
```

**Good**

```
var card = new Card(
    key: new ObjectKey(goal.id), // need to key off of the id field as it remains constant
    child: button
);
```

Answer (score 2):

That shouldn't stop the splash. The only reason the splash should stop is if you add or remove one of the widgets between the IconButton and the Material, or change its key, or change the Material's key, or move the Material in the tree. (Some of those are bugs in the framework right now, I hope to fix them in the coming months.)

Can you post a minimal app that shows the problem?

Meanwhile, we're tracking the issue at https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/6751 and https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/5456

Comment: What do you mean "that" ? The example in the question, or the example in the answer? Also, is there a link(s) to the bugs you are referring to? Thanks!

Comment: Bugs are https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/6751 and https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/5456.